# is there a inline editor option available?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

When am editing a large Q or A, I find it to be extremely annoying to edit something, and then have to browse/find that edit.

**Q**: Is there a inline editor option available for the 'stack exchange editor'?

<sup>Example</sup>

[image: ckeditor-inline]

Comment: What do you mean by "browse/find"? You can always use your browser's Ctrl+F, or Ctrl+End to go to the bottom or Ctrl+Home to go to the top.

Comment: @minerz029 I mean mean adding, a link, editing text, uploading images, the Q/A is simply to big and broad to find a link, image. When i using an inline editor, you can just click where u want to edit. and when browsing down, you can probably set a fixed position for the button bar. so

Comment: OK, I get what you mean. You want to have the toolbar stick with the scroll position. I guess you don't really need it for markdown. The only time you really need it is for images. (maybe there's an extension or plugin in the browser to save scrolling position)

Answer (score 1):

Markdown is meant to be intuitive and not need toolbars which MS Word or similar have in abundance. The syntax is simple and meant to just 'work' in the text.

Of the icons in the toolbar, you'll probably only use the `img` option for uploading images (can't be copy/pasted or dropped). You can also always use keyboard shortcuts to replace this (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd> for images or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for block code indentation).

It might also be worth writing these shortcuts to a text file (depending on how many long posts you edit):

```
Key        Description         HTML
----------------------------------------
Ctrl+B     Bold                <b>
Ctrl+I     Italic              <i>
Ctrl+L     Hyperlink           <a href="http://website">
Ctrl+Q     Blockquote          <blockquote>
Ctrl+K     Preformatted text   <pre><code>
Ctrl+G     Image               <img src="http://image">
Ctrl+O     Ordered list        <ol>
Ctrl+U     Bulleted list       <ul>
Ctrl+H     Heading             <h1> OR <h2>
Ctrl+R     Horizontal rule     <hr>
```

It may be faster typing the Markdown instead of keyboard shortcuts if you need a list of the keys.

---

GitHub goes so far as to not have a toolbar at all:
[image: GitHub without a toolbar!]

Comment: Right, but, Is there a inline editor option available for the 'stack exchange editor'?, or is there such a feature coming in the near future?

Comment: @blade I don't know, probably not.